# Good binning function for a highly skewed numeric variable in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Could you suggest a good function to bin the given highly skewed data into bins less than or equal to the desired number of bins, for example if i want to bin all the numeric variables in a dataframe into 10 bins, as the data has some highly skewed variables like a discrete variable with only 5 possible values it should split that variable into only 5 bins.
I have tried using the cut function in pandas but the results are not promising. Could you help me find a good function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If a particular column can only take on particular values, you can determine this values using the unique() method of the series, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

data_series = pd.Series([0,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])
unique_vals = list(data_series.unique())
if len(unique_vals) > 0.95*(len(data_series)):
    #almost all values are unique - plot a normal histogram
    matplotlib.pyplot.hist(data_series)
else:
    #many non-unique values - put each discrete value in its own bin
    #bins specifies the edges of the bins - need an extra edge to create a bin for the maximal value
    bins = unique_vals + [max(unique_vals)+1]
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.hist(data_series,bins=bins)
```

This will produce some strange looking histograms if you have very unevenly-spaced discrete values.

A more natural way to plot the discrete cases might be with a bar graph, for which you can use value_counts (might need to adjust bar widths depending on how close together your discrete values are, though):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(data_series.value_counts().index,data_series.value_counts())
```